# Proof: if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\bar{x}_n=\bar{x}\in \ell^\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\bar{x}_{nr}=x_r$ for all $r\geq1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am having trouble (because I don't know how to start) for proving that if we have a sequence ${(\bar{x}_n)}^\infty_{n=1}$ in $(\ell^\infty, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ and if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\bar{x}_n=\bar{x}\in \ell^\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\bar{x}_{nr}=x_r$ for all $r\geq1$.

Where $\bar{x}_n=(x_{n1},x_{n2},\ldots,x_{nr},\ldots)$ and $\bar{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r,\ldots)$.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: hint $|x_{nr}-x_r|\leq\Vert x_n-x\Vert\to_{n\to\infty}0$

Comment: @Norbert Thanks! Im working on it.

Comment: @Norbert I am going no where, I dont know how to use your hint.

Comment: I am confused with the $r$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By def'n $\lim_{n\to \infty}\bar x_n=\bar x \iff$ $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|\bar x_n-\bar x\|=0 \iff $ $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{s\in \Bbb N}|\bar x_{n,s}-\bar x_s|=0.$

If $\bar x_{n,r}$ does not converge to $\bar x_r$ as $n\to \infty$ then there exists $K>0$ such that $|\bar x_{n,r}-\bar x_r|>K$ for infinitely many $n.$

But then for infinitely many $n$ we have $\|\bar x_n-\bar x\|=$ $\sup_{s\in \Bbb N}|\bar x_{n,s}-\bar x_s|\ge$ $ |\bar x_{n,r}-\bar x_r|>K,$ implying that $\|\bar x_n-\bar x\|$ does not converge to $0.$

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot!